# Passing pointer into Class method

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and have a problem with pointers.
I want to pass a pointer into my method and assign it a new value. But my pointer is 0 after the method was called. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyObject
{
    public:
        bool search(int* a) 
        {
            int* test = new int(23);
            a = test;
            return true;
        }
};


MyObject* obj;

void search()
{
    int* test = NULL;
    obj->search(test);
    cout << test << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    obj = new MyObject();
    search();
}
```

Comment: @StaticBeagle None of the answers there seem to show how to pass a reference to a pointer. I'm not sure it's a good duplicate.

Comment: Unrelated: Consider making `obj` an automatic variable inside `main` and passing it into `search` as a parameter. Global variables are not strictly bad, but they can make your life harder than it needs to be as your programs grow more complex..

Comment: @rwp that code is only C if agajvery is using some really impressive macros.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the pointer by reference.

```
bool search(int*& a)
```

Without this, the pointer is passed by value, and you are only assigning a copy of what you passed. To assign the actual object/variable you pass, you need to pass the pointer by reference.

For further reading: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: Where is the explanation of why, and what's the difference, between pass-by-reference, and pass-by-value?

Comment: Added explanation

Comment: Perfect. Succinct and hits on all the key terms an asker needs to perform research for more information should they want it.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a local variable, if you set its value during the `search` method execution, it won't have any effect on the `test` variable in the free `search` function, because `a` is just a copy of `test`.

You should pass `a` by reference:

```
bool search(int *&a) { 
    int* test = new int(23);
    a = test; 
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pointer was passed by value instead of reference. Which means the local variable `test`'s value was not changed.

Instead do `bool search(int*& a)`

This will pass the reference to the method, which will update the local variable in the calling function.